# .Net BinaryWriter automatically flushes stream when checking stream Position

Tags: c#, .net, stream, .net-4.5, flush

Has anyone else seen this or know how to turn this off?

I have code which periodically checks the Position of a stream in a BinaryWriter.  Every invocation of the BinaryWriter.BaseStream.Position method results in that stream's Flush method being invoked.

I tried using a BinaryWriter and a StreamWriter, and only the BinaryWriter demonstrated this behavior.

Some sample code below:

```
namespace FlushaholicStreams
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var stream = new PrivateStream())
            using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
            {
                var data = "hi there, this is a really long string. Very very very long";

                for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
                {
                    data += data;
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                    writer.Write(bytes);
                    var position = writer.BaseStream.Position;
                    Console.WriteLine("The position was {0}", position);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("All done");
        }
    }

    class PrivateStream : MemoryStream
    {
        public int FlushCount = 0;
        public int CloseCount = 0;

        public override void Close()
        {
            this.CloseCount++;
            Console.WriteLine("Closing the stream");
            base.Close();
        }

        public override void Flush()
        {
            this.FlushCount++;
            Console.WriteLine("Flushing the stream");
            base.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

That code yields the output:

```
Flushing the stream
The position was 30932992
Flushing the stream
The position was 61865984
Flushing the stream
The position was 92798976
Flushing the stream
The position was 123731968
Flushing the stream
The position was 154664960
Flushing the stream
The position was 185597952
Flushing the stream
The position was 216530944
Flushing the stream
The position was 247463936
Flushed the stream 8 times
Closing the stream
Closing the stream
All done
```

I'm using .Net 4.5

Comment: Hadn't noticed it before... but it kind of makes sense. How can you tell for sure the actual position of the stream, if you have data yet to be flushed into it?

Comment: Are you strictly only reading from the stream?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. I'm looking at the source code for [the `FileStream.Position` property getter](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,f2e565bc5ce4ae5f) and there's nothing in there that would cause the `Flush()` method to be called. Please provide [a _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates precisely what you are asking.

Comment: @LeandroTaset No, I'm writing to the stream. The stream is writing data over the network and the excessive flushing is causing performance problems

Comment: @PeterDuniho You're right, I tried creating the minimal example and realized that this occurs only when the stream is inside a BinaryWriter and when I call BinaryWriter.BaseStream.Position

Comment: You could simply move the writer.BaseStream property getter outside of the loop and feel better about it.  It is however *not* the correct thing to do unless you have specific knowledge about the base stream type.  It is okay if it is a MemoryStream but then worrying about flushing is entirely pointless.

Comment: @HansPassant the actual streams I plan to use are FileStream and BlobStream (for Azure blob storage).  Is referencing the base stream really bad to do? Looking at the BinaryWriter source code (pasted in my answer) the BinaryWriter itself doesn't do anything when it flushes the stream. It just calls the stream's Flush() method. I would imagine a stream is capable of maintaining it's own position internally

Comment: Hard to see what you are fretting about, I think you are trying to solve a non-existing problem.  The obvious way to feel good about those flushes is to write to a MemoryStream and only write its content to the real stream after you've written a bunch of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the BinaryWriter class forces excessive Flushing and there's no way to override it.  I'll just keep a reference to the original stream and check position on it directly.

I found the (alleged) source code here:

http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/IO/BinaryWriter@cs/1305376/BinaryWriter@cs

```
/* 
* Returns the stream associate with the writer. It flushes all pending
* writes before returning. All subclasses should override Flush to 
* ensure that all buffered data is sent to the stream.
*/
public virtual Stream BaseStream {
  get { 
    Flush();
    return OutStream; 
  } 
}

// Clears all buffers for this writer and causes any buffered data to be
// written to the underlying device.
public virtual void Flush()
{ 
  OutStream.Flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The framework is prone to flushing, yes. That's bad because it forces disk access. (Subjective note: It's a design flaw.)

Write yourself a `Stream` that wraps another stream. In your wrapper class you override the necessary methods to maintain the `Position` yourself in an instance field. That way the `Position` member of the wrapped stream does not need to be accessed at all.